# Call an class object with a name that is from user-input

Tags: python, class, input

Basically, The user creates a creature by giving it a name, this name is then fed into the creation of the creature, where it is then given stats (This all works fine, even when making several creatures). However, I want to give the option to the user to check the stats of the creature they created through the 'check_stats()' function, they do this by inputting the slot number of the creature in their line-up, the code then finds the name of the creature through this, and calls the check_stat function using it. However this does not work as I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'check_stats'
```

If i create the creature manually in the code, like I write:

```
Bill = Pet('Bill')
```

It works perfectly and i can call the stats whenever.
Its just when the user creates the class instance, it does not work.

This is my code (That is the problem):

```
def create_creature():
    creature = Pet(name)
    creature.create_stats()
    print(" \n \n \n")

minions = {}
minion_value = {
    1: None,
    2: None,
    3: None,
    4: None,
    5: None,
    6: None
}

minion_slot = 0
for value in range(2):
    name = input("Create a pet!\n> ")
    minions[name] = create_creature()
    minion_slot += 1
    minion_value.update({minion_slot : name})


print("Your line-up")
for creature_ in minion_value:
    print("{}: {}".format(creature_, minion_value[creature_]))

check_creature = int(input("Which pet would you like to check? (number)\n> "))
for creature_ in minion_value:
    if check_creature == creature_:
                (minion_value[check_creature]).check_stats()
```

This is what the output of this code looks like:

```
Create a pet!
> Bob
---Bob---
3 years old 
5% healthy
66% happy
65% crazy
48% smarts
 
 
 

Create a pet!
> Bill
---Bill---
9 years old 
100% healthy
35% happy
93% crazy
13% smarts
 
 
 

Your line-up
1: Bob
2: Bill
3: None
4: None
5: None
6: None
Which pet would you like to check? (number)
> 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\c10ld\Downloads\Test_class_animals.py", line 103, in <module>
    (minion_value[check_creature]).check_stats()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'check_stats'
```

This is what it should look like:

```
Create a pet!
> Bob
---Bob---
3 years old 
5% healthy
66% happy
65% crazy
48% smarts
 
 
 

Create a pet!
> Bill
---Bill---
9 years old 
100% healthy
35% happy
93% crazy
13% smarts
 
 
 

Your line-up
1: Bob
2: Bill
3: None
4: None
5: None
6: None
Which pet would you like to check? (number)
> 1

Your Pet:
---Bob---
3 years old 
5% healthy
66% happy
65% crazy
48% smarts
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you! (Sorry if this is too long, its my first post and i wanted to make sure there was little to no confusion.)

EDIT:
Here is the rest of the code, including the Pet class:

```
import random



class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, age, health, happiness):
        self.age = 0
        self.health = 0
        self.happiness = 0
        
        
    def get_age(self):
        self.age = random.randint(8, 100)
 
    def get_health(self):
        self.health = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f"{self.health}% healthy")
     
    def get_happiness(self):
        self.happiness = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f"{self.happiness}% happy")
        
    def age_up(self):
        self.age += 1
        print(f"{int(round(self.age, 0))} years old")
        
        if self.age < 17:    
                self.age_up()
            
        elif self.age >= 17:
                print("died of age.")



class Pet(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.craziness = 0
        self.intelligence = 0
    
    
    def pet_age(self):
       self.get_age()
       self.age = self.age / 7
       print(f"{int(round(self.age, 0))} years old ")
       
         
    def get_craziness(self):
        self.craziness = random.randint(1,100)
        print(f"{self.craziness}% crazy")
        
    def get_intelligence(self):
        self.intelligence = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f"{self.intelligence}% smarts")
        
    def create_stats(self):
         print(f"---{self.name}---")
         self.pet_age()
         self.get_health()
         self.get_happiness()
         self.get_craziness()
         self.get_intelligence()
         
    def check_stats(self):
         print(f"---{self.name}---")
         print(f"{int(round(self.age, 0))} years old")
         print(f"{self.health}% healthy")
         print(f"{self.happiness}% happy")
         print(f"{self.craziness}% crazy")
         print(f"{self.intelligence}% smarts")
```

I created an 'Animal' class as i was planning on creating more sub-classes, such as workers and warriors!

Comment: `create_creature` returns `None`, not the `Pet` instance you created. Then your `dict` maps an integer to the pet's name, not the (unavailable) `Pet` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are storing just the name of the creature in your `minion_value` dictionary. This is why `(minion_value[check_creature])` from

```py
check_creature = int(input("Which pet would you like to check? (number)\n> "))
for creature_ in minion_value:
    if check_creature == creature_:
                (minion_value[check_creature]).check_stats()
```

is returning a `str` which has no check_stats method defined from your custom `Pet` class.

So, we can do this.

```py
for value in range(2):
    name = input("Create a pet!\n> ")
    minions[name] = create_creature(name)
    minion_value.append(minions[name])
```

and for the `create_creature` function,

```py
def create_creature(name: str) -> Pet:
    creature = Pet(name)
    creature.create_stats()
    print(" \n \n \n")
    return creature
```

Thank you for providing further code! Let's see..

```py
class Pet(Animal):
    ...(after __init__)...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # it's that simple :)
```

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and `__repr__` is for more technical representations whereas `__str__` is for the end user, like the player.

We can also add getter and setter decorators to the code for more elegance. I'll add that soon too!

To improve readability and reduce memory usage, we can also use a list instead a dictionary for the `minion_value` object. Edit: Thank you for your reply. I changed the for loop code above for reference.

And as others have suggested, it is wise to constrain global variables and pass necessary arguments as a parameter to a function. Edit: Great you stuck with it! I'm glad it worked as you intended.

Thank you for your question, and your game looks really fun!

Edit: As we changed the `minion_value` to be an empty list `minion_value = []`, we should change the `line_up` code as well. `f-strings` are a useful toolkit for formatting. [see here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```py
print("Your line-up")
for i, creature_ in enumerate(minion_value):
    print(f"{i}: {creature_}")
```

or

```py
print("Your line-up")
for i in range(1, 7):
    try:
        print(f"{i}: {minion_value[i]}")
    except IndexError:
        print(f"{i}: None")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried out your code and it fetches the correct stuff. Many Thanks, I will provide the rest of the code for you to work that out.

With reference to your question on using list, i did not think to use the list.

Should I put my pet class code into the main body of the question? As it does not fit in the comment. :)
(Also my apologies for the late reply, i did not realise people would respond so quick haha!)

Comment: Hello, @Anyx ! I am thrilled to hear that it helped. I have made edits to the answer, and if you have more questions I would love to hear them :D

Comment: Hello! :)
Thank you for the edits, i am trying to insert them now to see if it works. I will definitely respond with more questions if I have any! :)

With regards to the 
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
What does this do exactly? Thank you :)

Comment: UPDATE:
After modifying the code to add your edit, I get a new error:
'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

I do not know if this is due to me forgetting to modify something else to work this code or not. Thank you :)

Comment: @Anyx Yes, I forgot to address the line-up code which will throw a TypeError. Would you please try with the updated line-up code? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, I used the second one due to it including the 'None' parts and it works! Using this, will it limit the length of the list to 6? So for example, if I create more than 6 pets, what will happen to the list? As i want to limit the line-up to 6, which will then be offered to replace one upon creation of yet another pet. Many thanks again for your expertise. :D

Comment: Thank YOU for programming, @Anyx. In that case, it might be better to initialize minion_value to a list of 6 `None`s and update the slots. May the player choose a slot, or is it on a sequential basis like 1, 2, 3?

Comment: That sounds like it could be a good idea!
Before the 6 slots are filled, they are selected in a sequential order, once they're full, i would like the player to pick which slot to replace :)
Also, i know i have asked you for too much as it is, since the most recent edits to the code, the first problem with the check_stats() has slightly re-emerged, not in the same sense, but the code does not list anything so i believe it is to do with the 'if' statements and 'for' loops at the end, would you please take a look to see if any names/references need to be changed? Thank you! :D

Comment: Also, if it is not too much work, what can I do to change the input part from being the number to the name of the pet? I.E: instead of inputting '1' they instead input 'Bob', which then lists 'Bob's' stats? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable as an argument:

Random example (you should be able to apply the same logic to your code):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

my_name = input("What is your name? ")
p = Person(my_name)
print(p.name)
```

Output:

```
What is your name? 
Ryan
Ryan
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with the code here.

Firstly, `create_creature` does not return anything, which in Python means return `None`, so I don't think you know what you meant to store in minions when you do `minions[name] = create_creature()`.

Then, `create_creature` also appears to be using a `name` variable, which is not assigned in it or given as argument, so where does the name come from ?

Then, the `minion_value` is a dict with integer keys from 1 to 7, that looks like a list to me.

Finally, you are storing `name` in `minion_value` which must be a str rather than a Pet, and so that is why you get the attribute error for missing `.check_stats()`, which is defined for `Pet` but not `str`.